# Как создать авто генерируемые ссылки, например, на магазины?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть слайдер, в котором отображаются разные магазины. Магазины добавляются через админку. В этом слайдере есть несколько магазинов с заголовком, фото и адресом.
Но ссылок ни на один магазин нет. У меня есть старница(шаблон) где должно быть видно магазин полностью, при нажании на заголовок магазина в слайдере.
В базе 3 столбцаid, title, address.
title, address. я вивел. Теперь как я понимаю нужно использовать `$_GET[]` что бы передать параметры
Что я пишу в url ссылки(заголовка магазина) `<a href="?stores&id=<?=$stores['id'] ?>"><h3 class="title"><?= $stores['title']?></h3></a>`
?stores&id= Я раньше делал немного сайты на ВП и там при создани например новой категории или подобного создание url происходит автоматически. Сейчас у меня получается в url http://prntscr.com/d4m477 такое get параметр stores и id. Как вывести на отдельную страницу, именно тот магазин на который я нажму?

ЗЫ. `?stores&id=` get паарменты всегда нужно вносить вручную отталкиваясь от логики названий того куда мы хотим пеерйти по этому адрессу?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала ты должен проверить, есть ли что то в $_GET

```
$stores = (isset($_GET['id'],$_GET['stores ']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : false);
if($stores){
  //Тут мы уже знаем что пользователь запрашивает магазин, но мы не можем быть уверены, пока ты не отправишь запрос.
  // "SELECT * FROM название таблицы WHERE `id` = '".$stores."'" ->fetch()
}
```

Напиши что у тебя используется для работы с базой (PDO,Своё и тд, мб движок какой то ты используешь (я помогу переписать под твое конкретное решение))

Тк я не знаю как у тебя организован код, то не могу с точностью сказать как лучше тебе организовать отдельную страницу для твоего магазина. Покажи пожалуйста кусок страницы по которму можно будет понять как у тебя все организовано

Comment: Спасибо, движок свой самописный, использую mysql для подключения к базе, ООП не использую пока.

Comment: Покажи код страницы, я помогу реализовать

Comment: Вот код http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/efc183e6a34f7aad1eb33d26ed332d68fcfd33ff

Comment: Посмотри,сверху поставил условие, и в нем получаем магазин. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b3eb8ca75ba0cd4819b54251c228ade56cf2c758

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю.